# pulling pages from a pdf file and display it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, user-interface

this is just a rough idea, i am trying to create a magazine reading platform and i need the reading flow to be smooth, and so is the magazine upload process, it must be fast and easy. so i am thinking of using pdf file.

I am thinking is it possible to have a module(maybe a system?) to pull each page from the pdf and display it in a interface written in html? i know there is something similar in flash, but what i want it is something lighter and easier from development. coz at the end i am gonna put this module into maybe a cms system.

thanks in advance guys:)

Regards,
WJ

Comment: You should include the back end you plan on using, so that people can suggest appropriate assemblies to handle the PDF dis-assembly.  If you're using .NET, check out itextsharp.

Comment: @rkw come on! don't recommend a tool if you haven't used it. itext/itextsharp can't be used to convert PDF to HTML. And they can't be used to display PDF either.

Comment: @Bobrovsky: I use it exclusively at my company.  It's one of the few open source assemblies that can handle much more complicated annotations (e.g. putting a barcode inside an object that can still be moved around.  Note: not a stamp).  It's perfect for this job because you can strip the PDF down into images (you don't need it to be HTML), and display that for the user by pages, bypassing the need for flash, which would make it lighter weight and easier to index.  Which tool would you use?

Comment: @rkw ok, I was wrong about your experience with itextsharp. Sorry.

Comment: I would not recommend itextsharp for the task because it's not very good at reading PDF files, it can't be used to create images from pages and it has viral AGPL 3 license.

Comment: wow guys thanks for the suggestions and sorry for the late reply, i will go and try out itextsharp since i don't have other solutions. by the way i am really confuse about what to use since this project is something more tend to be like a software development project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi guys i just found this solution, pdf.js, it uses javacript to implement pdf displaying on the web page, it also able to create pdf file from javascript.

anyway the reader is there, and interface is able to change since it is html, i guess this should be the solution.